# Microsoft Teams API returning Unauthorized

Tags: vb.net, botframework, microsoft-teams

So I am working on setting up a new (private) bot for Microsoft Teams that should be able to post messages in a channel on-demand. I already have a bot coded for Google Hangouts Chat, but Microsoft Teams is giving me a really hard time.

I've been searching for over 10 hours now all over the web, and I am very confused.

Right now, all I want to do is post cards to a Microsoft Teams Channel. So I created the connectorclient, I used the baseuri provided when the bot joined the channel (Starts with `smba.trafficmanager.net`) with my MSAppID and MSAppPassword. Then, I fill in as much information as I can (Maybe too much?) and I submit the information using the connector's `.conversations.createconversation`.

Namespaces used: `Microsoft.bot.connector`, `Microsoft.bot.connector.teams.models`

Here's the code:

```
Dim Connector As New ConnectorClient(New Uri("https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/"), "MSAPPID", "MSAPPPASSWORD")

Dim conversation As New ConversationParameters
Dim activity2 = Activity.CreateMessageActivity

Dim bot As New ChannelAccount
bot.Id = "BOTID"
bot.Name = "EDD Bot Test"
conversation.Bot = bot

Dim chaninfo As New ChannelInfo
chaninfo.Id = "CHANID"
chaninfo.Name = "General"

Dim teaminfo As New TeamInfo
teaminfo.Id = "TEAMID"
teaminfo.Name = "EDD"

activity2.Text = "Test"
activity2.ServiceUrl = "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/"
activity2.Type = ActivityTypes.Message
activity2.From = bot
activity2.ChannelId = "msteams"

Dim tenantdata As New TenantInfo
tenantdata.Id = "TENANTID"

Dim teamschanneldata As New TeamsChannelData
teamschanneldata.Channel = chaninfo
teamschanneldata.Team = teaminfo
teamschanneldata.Tenant = tenantdata
activity2.ChannelData = teamschanneldata

conversation.Activity = activity2
Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conversation))
Try
  Dim reqresp As ConversationResourceResponse = Connector.Conversations.CreateConversation(conversation)
  Response.Write("ActivityID: " & reqresp.ActivityId & ", ServiceURL: " & reqresp.ServiceUrl & ", ID: " & reqresp.ServiceUrl)
Catch ex As ErrorResponseException
  Response.Write(ex.Response.Content & " " & ex.Response.ReasonPhrase)
End Try
```

This is what the API returns:

```
{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."} Unauthorized
```

Keep in mind, I'm not even 100% sure I'm using the right method to create the channel message, I figured it was either `CreateConversation` or `ReplyToActivity`.

I gave the app `Users.ReadWriteAll` permissions too, so am I missing something? That error leads me to think it doesn't have anything to do with the ConversationParameters payload but something to do with authentication.

Comment: I was able to get it fixed. I added MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustserviceUrl for both the serviceurl and the endpoint message.

Comment: If you could, please add that as a formal answer so that you can get credit for it if other users have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by using `MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustserviceUrl` for both the serviceUrl and the endpoint message.